# dropdown button to interact with a graph using jupyter bokeh by changing the y and x axis

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am fairly new to bokeh(using jupyter) and I was trying to create a simple line and scatter graph with a drop-down button where I could select a set of values for x-axis and y-axis and see them being updated in real time but for some reason for the graph does not get updated correctly this is a portion of my code:

```
weight= [23,45,11,40]
velocity= [12,65,32,15]
momentum = [12,78,22,40]

p = figure(plot_height=300,plot_width=500,title="Graph line of DATA")
p.title.text_font_style = "bold"
r = p.line(weight,velocity, color="red", line_width=3)
tab1=Panel(child=p, title="line")

p1 = figure(plot_height=300,plot_width=500,title="Graph line of DATA")
r1 = p1.circle(weight,velocity, size=10, color="red", alpha=0.5)
p1.title.text_font_style = "bold"
tab2=Panel(child=p1, title="Circle")


def updatex(Xaxis):

    if Xaxis == "Weight":
        func = weight
        p.xaxis.axis_label = "pounds"
        p1.xaxis.axis_label = "pounds"

    elif Xaxis == "Velocity":
        func = velocity
        p.xaxis.axis_label = "m/s"
        p1.xaxis.axis_label = "m/s"

    elif Xaxis == "Momemtum":
        func = momentum
        p.xaxis.axis_label = "lb-sec"
        p1.xaxis.axis_label = "lb-sec"

    r.data_source.data['x'] = func
    r1.data_source.data['x'] = func
    push_notebook()

def updatey(Yaxis):

if Yaxis == "Weight":
    func = weight
    p.xaxis.axis_label = "pounds"
    p1.xaxis.axis_label = "pounds"

elif Yaxis == "Velocity":
    func = velocity
    p.xaxis.axis_label = "m/s"
    p1.xaxis.axis_label = "m/s"

elif Xaxis == "Momemtum":
    func = momentum
    p.xaxis.axis_label = "lb-sec"
    p1.xaxis.axis_label = "lb-sec"

r.data_source.data['y'] = func
r1.data_source.data['y'] = func
push_notebook()

# the following snippet would be in the following cell below:

interact(updatex,Xaxis=["Weight", "Velocity", "Momemtum"])
interact(updatey,Yaxis=["Weight","Velocity","Momemtum"])
```